# Git: conflicts when pulling latest version of the current branch

Tags: git

I'm afraid this must have been asked thousands of times but I haven't found it anywhere and it happens to me all the time.

At work, when I try to pull the latest commits on the branch that I currently have checked out, I get conflict errors. This happens to me even if I haven't made any changes to the branch.

So I end up deleting my local branch and fetching the branch as if it were brand new.

This is an example of what I'm describing:

```
➜  my_project git:(foo_branch) ✗ git pull
From github.com:Blabla/my_project
 + c6a6ccf...39052a7 foo_branch -> origin/foo_branch  (forced update)
 + aa9d3a9...22cdf8c development                    -> origin/development  (forced update)
 * [new branch]      docs/DE3802                    -> origin/docs/DE3802
   0b2ed86..1256c5c  docs/US16862                   -> origin/docs/US16862
   15a755b..8a3ebdd  master                         -> origin/master
Auto-merging cloudformation/appsync/schema.graphql
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in my_project/media/clients/foo/file_1
Auto-merging my_project/media/clients/foo/policy_coverages
Auto-merging my_project/apps/engine/tests/test_functions.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in my_project/apps/engine/tests/test_functions.py
Auto-merging my_project/apps/engine/functions.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in my_project/apps/engine/functions.py
Auto-merging my_project/apps/engine/defaults.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in my_project/apps/engine/defaults.py
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

How can I just pull the latest changes in the branch and make them overwrite the older version I have?

Comment: Please do not close this as "overwrite files". That is not the issue. I'm working on an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone has been altering history and force pushing their branches.

tl;dr: Don't make local branches unless you need to make changes. Instead of creating and checking out `foo_branch`, checkout `origin/foo_branch`.

tl;dr: Use `git pull --rebase` to replay your local changes on top of the remote branch. I recommend rebasing all pulls. It is safe. You can do so by adding this to your `.gitconfig`.

```
[pull]
        rebase = merges
```

---

A `git pull` is a `git fetch` plus a `git merge`. The first portion of the `git pull` is a record of the `git fetch` portion to update your remote tracking branches.

```
From github.com:Blabla/my_project
 + c6a6ccf...39052a7 foo_branch -> origin/foo_branch  (forced update)
 + aa9d3a9...22cdf8c development                    -> origin/development  (forced update)
 * [new branch]      docs/DE3802                    -> origin/docs/DE3802
   0b2ed86..1256c5c  docs/US16862                   -> origin/docs/US16862
   15a755b..8a3ebdd  master                         -> origin/master
```

Let's focus on just `foo_branch`.

```
 + c6a6ccf...39052a7 foo_branch -> origin/foo_branch  (forced update)
```

This says that the remote branch `foo_branch` is being tracked locally in `origin/foo_branch`. You had `origin/foo_branch` at `c6a6ccf`. The fetch moved it to `39052a7`. `+`, `(forced_update)` and `...` indicate it was not a "fast-forward".

---

A "fast-forward" is when a branch can be updated with no merge. For example...

```
A - B - C [master]
         \
          D - E [feature]
```

If we `git merge feature` into master there is no need for a merge, Git will simply move the `master` label to the same commit as `feature`.

```
$ git merge feature

# Fast forward master from C to E.
A - B - C - D - E [master]
                  [feature]
```

OTOH if master had changes, a merge would be necessary to combine both the changes in feature with the new changes in master.

```
A - B - C - F [master]
         \
          D - E [feature]

$ git merge feature

A - B - C - F - G [master]
         \     /
          D - E [feature]
```

---

Normally, `git fetch` is a fast forward. `origin/foo_branch` is a snapshot of your last `git fetch`. You should have no additional changes to `origin/foo_branch` so any new changes can be fast forwarded. Here's what that might look like. Remember, a `git pull origin foo_branch` is a `git fetch origin` and `git merge foo_branch origin/foo_branch`.

```
origin
A - B - C - D - E [foo_branch]

local
A - B - C [foo_branch]
          [origin/foo_branch]

$ git fetch origin

local
A - B - C [foo_branch]
         \
          D - E [origin/foo_branch]

$ git merge foo_branch origin/foo_branch

# Fast-forward foo_branch from C to E.
A - B - C - D - E [origin/foo_branch]
```

But what happens if someone rebases `foo_branch` and does a force push?

```
origin
A - B1 - C1 - D - E [foo_branch]

local
A - B - C [foo_branch]
          [origin/foo_branch]

$ git fetch origin

local
A - B1 - C1 - D - E [origin/foo_branch]
 \
  B - C [foo_branch]
```

B1 and C1 represent rebased commits. After the fetch `foo_branch` and `origin/foo_branch` have "diverged". The next part of `git pull` cannot fast-forward and requires a merge.

```
$ git merge foo_branch origin/foo_branch

local
A - B1 - C1 - D - E [origin/foo_branch]
 \                 \
  B - C ------------ M [foo_branch]
```

Even though there were no local changes to `foo_branch`, there are likely to be conflicts between B and B1 and C and C1.

---

So, what to do about it.

First, don't make local branches if you don't need to make local changes. Instead of making a local `foo_branch`, reference `origin/foo_branch`. Then there is no local branch to fall out of sync.

Second, change `git pull` so it does a rebase instead of a merge. You can do this individually with `git pull --rebase` and globally by setting `pull.rebase` to `merges`.

Going back to our example above where `foo_branch` and `origin/foo_branch` have diverged after `foo_branch` was remotely rebased...

```
origin
A - B1 - C1 - D - E [foo_branch]

local
A - B - C [foo_branch]
          [origin/foo_branch]
```

`git pull --rebase` will not attempt a merge. It will instead rebase your local changes to `foo_branch` on top of the new `origin/foo_branch`. There are no local changes, so `foo_branch` is simply brought up to date with the new `origin/foo_branch`.

```
local
A - B1 - C1 - D - E [foo_branch]
                    [origin/foo_branch]
```

If you did have changes, they would be replayed on top of the new `origin/foo_branch`.

```
origin
A - B1 - C1 - D - E [foo_branch]

local
A - B - C [origin/foo_branch]
         \          
          F - G [foo_branch]

$ git pull --rebase

local
A - B1 - C1 - D - E [origin/foo_branch]
                   \          
                    F - G [foo_branch]
```

Third, discuss procedures around forced pushes with other members of your project.

Comment: this is an amazing super clarifying explanation. Thank you so much! I'll try all suggestions on Monday at work.

Comment: I don't understand the advice to `checkout origin/foo_branch`. Why would one checkout a remote-tracking branch? What can you do from here, other than look around in detached head mode?

Comment: @matt Exactly, you can look at the branch without making a local one. The OP mentioned "*This happens to me even if I haven't made any changes to the branch.*" In those cases they don't need a local branch. One less local branch to maintain.

Comment: Right, I see, your theory is that the OP has been making a local branch merely to do the work of a remote-tracking branch. And then when you combine that with someone force-pushing on that branch on the remote, Bad Things happen.